# Laravel get route by locale

Tags: php, laravel

Currently, I've got the following route in my web app.

```
Route::get(__('routes.account.dogs'), 
    [DogController::class, 'index'])->name('dog.index')->middleware('auth');
```

I specify the URL translation for the route in two different language files.

```
return [
    //Account
    'account' => [
        'dogs' => 'honden',
    ]
];
```

When I send a queued email with this link, I want to translate the link on the user's locale (saved in the database). So I want to get this route based on the user's locale, but `app()->setLocale($user->locale);` cannot be used because it's a queued job. How can I fix this?

In a perfect world it would be something like:

```
route('dog.index', [], $user->locale);
```

Comment: Not the best way to use a third party package, but you can take a look to https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization#get-url-for-an-specific-translation-key

Comment: Why can't you use that in a Job?

Answer (score 3):

laravel **__()** helper function also accepts the optional 3rd argument **$locale** for setting the locale to translate.

So you could use the **$user->locale** in the helper as follows.

```
url(__('account.dogs', [], $user->locale));
```

Comment: Yes indeed! but then I still need to do something with the domain. For example `.de` or `.com`

Comment: how many different domains you have?

Answer (score 1):

As [@Vincent Decaux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/999617/vincent-decaux) suggested, you need a library to make your life easier. You could use the one they use or the one I use [arcanedev/localization](https://github.com/ARCANEDEV/Localization).

Once you set a middleware, everything will be taken care of. But I am concerned regarding your comment:

> Yes indeed! but then I still need to do something with the domain. For example .de or .com

Why not use the current domain (.com?) and simply add a directory /en or whatever locale you need instead? It seems inconvenient to me to change the entire domain.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Mail::to(), you can use locale() to choose the translation

```php
Mail::to($user->email)
    ->locale($user->locale)
    ->queue(new YourEmail());
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#localizing-mailables